# how i get a ajax value into twig template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

Please, I need some help.

first at all, my apology for my english level.

I try to set a dinamic value into a Symfony embed form. So, I'm using ajax for refresh the view. For to do that, I try to get a field value that I send from the request. But, although the request bring the value, I don't get into twig. 
This is the jquery function with i'm sending the value:

```
$selprod.combobox({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $fam = $selprod.val();
        var $form = $('form[name="orden_index"]');
        var data = {};
        data[$selprod.attr('name')] = $selprod.val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#testprod').replaceWith(
                        $(html).find('#testprod')
                        );
            }
        });
    }
}
);
```

as i say before, ajax passes the value into the request (I can see with the debbuger).
This is the code with I catch the value into twig template:

```
{% set variable = app.request.get('orden_index[lineas][1][producto]') %}
{% debug variable %}
```

"orden_index[lineas][1][producto]" is the name of the combobox where I get the value. With this value, I can calculate the value that i want show dynamically. Before the combobox is selected, the request bring the 'orden_index' form values, what is normal. When combobox is selected, ajax sends the value normally, I can see it in the php debugger, but Twig dont get it.

for example, if i write in twig the follow code:

```
{% set variable = app.request.get('orden_index') %}
{% debug variable %}
```

the first time, the twig debbuger show me this:

```
array (size=3)
  'familia' => string '1' (length=1)
  'seleccionar' => string '' (length=0)
  '_token' => string 'c08OkhDO7PF37B5gWRUnWHhFbzMEuLBd1CzOutlYeUU' (length=43)
```

what is ok, but when I selected a value into combobox, and the request brings the value selected (namely, in this case, an array [lineas][1][producto]), twig debbuger continues to show the same first value.

thank you very much in advance

Comment: you don't. twig is a PHP templating engine, which means it runs on the server. By the time your AJAX code reaches the client and actually executes, twig has done its thing and produced the page. e.g. you're trying to do "How can I add mushrooms to the lasagna after its been baked?"

Comment: Would not run the action again and reload the template?... I have the same type of dinamic value into another form, except that this isn't a embed form. I write {% if form.vars.value.producto is not null %}{{ osch_producto.getNombreById(form.vars.value.producto) }} {% endif %} into twig template and i get the 'produto' field value after that it's selected (I don't can make that in this case, because the embed form isn't initialized yet). why twig is reloaded then and can not this?